# Why is Hochschild cohomology $HH^n(A, A)$ not a functor of $A$?

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, hochschild-cohomology

Let $k$ be a commutative ring, $A$ a $k$-algebra and $HH^n(A, M)$ the $n$-th Hochschild cohomology of $A$ with coefficients in the $A$-bimodule $M$. In the book Cyclic Homology by Loday the following curious few lines appear on page 40 when talking about the form that the coefficients can take:

> For $M=A$ the groups $HH^n(A, A)$ have been extensively studied in the literature because they are related to deformation theory. But one should note that they are *not* functors of $A$. However if $M = A^* = \mbox{Hom}_k(A, k)$, then the groups $HH^n(A, A^*)$ are indeed functors of $A$.

Now I'm quite confused by this assertion that $HH^n(A, A)$ isn't a functor of $A$, because I know that you can interpret the $n$-th cohomology as the derived functor

$$HH^n(A, M) = \mbox{Ext}_{A^e}^n(A, M)$$

where $A^e = A\otimes_k A^{op}$ is the enveloping algebra of $A$. In fact, it's mentioned on the very next page of the book. So clearly each $HH^n(A, M)$ is a functor if I've understood this correctly. So presumably the important part is that $HH^n(A, A)$ is not a functor "of $A$", but I'm not entirely sure what this means. I'd be grateful if someone could help me understand how it is that $HH^n(A, A)$ isn't a functor of $A$.

**Edit:**

Thanks to the comments beneath the question (thanks for your help guys, I appreciate it) I think I have a better idea of what's going on. So using the example of $\mbox{Hom}_k(A, A)$, the reason why this isn't a functor of $A$ is because given another $k$-algebra $B$, and a map $f:A\to B$, there is no real way of assigning $f$ to a map

$$\mbox{Hom}_k(A, A)\to\mbox{Hom}_k(B, B)$$

However, now that I understand this, it seems to me $\mbox{Hom}_k(A, A^*)$ suffers from the same issue. So how is it that (as mentioned in the paragraph I cite above) $HH^n(A, A^*)$ *is* a functor of $A$? Am I just missing some obvious way of assigning $f:A\to B$ to $\mbox{Hom}_k(A, A^*)\to\mbox{Hom}_k(B, B^*)$?

Comment: $A$ appears in the formula $\textrm{Ext}^n_{A^e} (A, A)$ several times, but not all with the same variance. So it isn't obviously a functor of $A$. (Recall that a functor acts on objects _and_ morphisms. Can you define the action on morphisms here?)

Comment: @ZhenLin I don't really know what you mean. What do you mean by "not all with the same variance"? And how does that indicate that it isn't a functor of $A$?

Comment: Well, for example, $\textrm{Hom} (X, Y)$ is contravariant in $X$ and covariant in $Y$. Thus $X$ appears in the expression $\textrm{Hom} (X, X)$ with mixed variance – and this is essentially the reason why $\textrm{End} (X)$ is not a functor of $X$. Hochschild cohomology is just a souped up version of this.

Comment: @ZhenLin Ok but what does "a functor of $X$" mean though? And why does the mixed variance mean that it isn't one of those?

Comment: It's not something that has a formal meaning. Roughly speaking it means an expression that assigns objects of one category to objects of another category is not the object part of a functor. Being of mixed variance does not, strictly speaking, imply that an expression is not functorial – but it certainly means that functoriality is not automatic and needs to be justified if true. (Besides, there are cheats to make expressions of mixed variance functorial, but they involve replacing contextual assumptions.)

Comment: @ZhenLin I do appreciate your effort to help me, so you'll have to forgive me, but I still don't really understand what you're saying. I get that functors assign objects of one category to objects of another, but what you mean by ".. is not the object part of a functor"? And I still don't really understand *why* the mixed variance has anything to do with a possible failure of functoriality.

Comment: @SeraPhim Maybe it's easier to see in the case of $\mathrm{Hom}(X,X)$ in some category, which is basically the same issue. If you want to make this a functor, then given $f:X\to Y$ you have to define a map in one direction or the other between $\mathrm{Hom}(X,X)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(Y,Y)$, and in general there is no reasonable way to do this.

Comment: @SeraPhim I hope you know that a functor also assigns morphisms of one category to morphisms of another, in such a way that preserves identity and composition. By abuse of notation and appeal to "common sense" the action of functors on morphisms is almost never made explicit, but it is something that is required to define a functor. This is one situation where "common sense" fails to supply the action on morphisms.

Comment: @KevinArlin Ah yes that makes sense, thank you! I got there eventually :') But doesn't $\mbox{Hom}_k(X, X^*)$ suffer from exactly the same problem? There doesn't seem to a way of defining a map between $\mbox{Hom}_k(X, X^*)$ and $\mbox{Hom}_k(Y, Y^*)$ and yet this is somehow a functor, at least according to my book, since it's the same as $HH^0(X, X^*)$.

Comment: @SeraPhim: Given a map $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$, you have an induced pullback map $f^{*} \colon \operatorname{Hom}_k(Y,Y^{*}) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_k(X,X^{*})$ given by $((f^{*}(\phi))(x))(x') = (\phi(f(x)))(f(x'))$. Similarly, you can define a map $f^{*} \colon C^n(B,B^{*}) \rightarrow C^n(A,A^{*})$ which commutes with the differential and induces a map on the Hochschild cohomology.

Comment: The point is that dualisation $(-)^*$ is a contravariant functor. Thus $\textrm{Hom} (X, X^*)$ is purely contravariant in $X$. More to the point, functors can be composed, and we have functors $X \mapsto (X, X^*)$ and $(X, Y) \mapsto \textrm{Hom} (X, Y)$, so we have the composite functor $X \mapsto \textrm{Hom} (X, X^*)$. By contrast $X \mapsto (X, X)$ and $(X, Y) \mapsto \textrm{Hom} (X, Y)$ cannot be composed because of incompatible variance.

Comment: @levap awesome thanks very much. Makes sense now!

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks for the clarifications, I appreciate your help!

Comment: If any of you guys want to post what you've written as answers I'd be happy to give them upvotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $A$ appears in the formula $\textrm{Ext}^n_{A^e} (A, A)$ several times, but not all with the same variance. So it isn't obviously a functor of $A$.

> [...] $\textrm{Hom} (X, Y)$ is contravariant in $X$ and covariant in $Y$. Thus $X$ appears in the expression $\textrm{Hom} (X, X)$ with mixed variance – and this is essentially the reason why $\textrm{End} (X)$ is not a functor of $X$. Hochschild cohomology is just a souped up version of this.

> Maybe it's easier to see in the case of $\mathrm{Hom}(X,X)$ in some category, which is basically the same issue. If you want to make this a functor, then given $f:X\to Y$ you have to define a map in one direction or the other between $\mathrm{Hom}(X,X)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(Y,Y)$, and in general there is no reasonable way to do this.